# Equivalent of the following SQL Count to LINQ Count

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, count

i have some problem with LINQ,
my problem is similar to the example below,
I have a table named History with the following data

```
Method DateUsed

A      2013/02/01
A      2013/01/01
B      2013/01/01
B      2012/01/01 <--
C      2013/01/01
C      2012/02/01
```

what i want is to get the number or the count of methods that were used in a specific year, if i want to get the year =2013 the result would be:

```
Method Total 

A       2
B       1 <--
C       3
```

in SQL my query would be something like

```
Select Method, Count(DateUsed) as Total from history 
where YEAR(DateUsed) = '2013' group by Method
```

however, i can't figure out how to do it in LINQ, can someone help me with the LINQ equivalent?

thanks in advance

Comment: try to use this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in linq to entities, you'll need [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx).

```
var result = context.History
                    //linq to entities
                    .Where(m => SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", DateUsed) == 2013)
                    //linq to object
                    .Where(m => m.DateUsed.Year == 2013)
                    //common part
                    .GroupBy(m => m.Method)
                    .Select(g => new {
                        Method = g.Key,
                        Total = g.Count()
                    });
```

Comment: @Cyborgx37 you're perfectly right (at least, if you want the code to compile ;) )

Answer (score 1):

You ll use a query similar as your SQL for LINQ. Group by Method and then select the method and count.

```
var result = History.Where(H=>H.DateUsed.Year == 2013)
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Method)
                    .Select(g => new {Method = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, this one just makes use of the LINQ query syntax:

```
var result = 
    from m in context.History
    where m.DateUsed.Year == 2013
    /* or where SqlFunctions.DatePart( "YEAR", m.DateUsed ) == 2013 */
    group m by m.Year into g
    select new { Method = g.Key, Total = g.Count() };
```

I find that the query syntax is easier to use in some circumstances, and that the LINQ extension methods are easier to use in others. It helps to be familiar with both.

*Note: not tested*

Comment: Note that the technical term is "query syntax", not "LINQ language".  Technically LINQ is the methods in the System.Linq namespace, so the other answers are using LINQ, and technically the query syntax doesn't *need* to be used in conjunction with LINQ, it can be used to map to other methods.

Comment: @Servy - I didn't think I was using the right terminology. Thanks.